# Stock android moving app to SD card force close applications

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, stock-android, app2sd

i am using stock android on my Micromax Canvas A1 (Android one) with android 4.4.4, it works pretty well but issue occurs when i move my install application to SD card and clear its data as well catch (tried in either way) then every application which i moved has been crashing on launching and can't use it, if i move them back to phone memory then strangely it works like charm, Other issue i been facing is sometimes i try to make call then contact/people have been force closed? does any one provide me solution? or anyone having information why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KitKat doesn't allow you to move apps to the SD card, only to "external storage," which is often a separate partition of **internal** storage. If your specific device doesn't have a separate "external storage" area, then it could actually be using the SD card (which is rare in KitKat), in which case there could be a problem with your SD card.

First off, make sure that the apps you are moving support running from external storage. The Applications Settings panel should be able to tell you this, just in case app2sd is getting it wrong somehow. You should also know that some apps don't work well outside of internal storage even though they've been marked as supporting it.

I'm also assuming here that you're not moving Package Manager or any internal app to the SD card, and that when you "move my install application" really means "move applications that I've installed."

Regarding Contacts stopping unexpectedly, I've experienced that as well. I'm afraid I don't have an answer for that yet.